# Why bootstrap css (3.2) can work on mobile and desktop

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Forgive me I am a newbie for the BootStrap. I was reading the tutorial [Bootstrap Css Getting Start](http://getbootstrap.com/css/). and there is a sample in the tutorial.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
  <!-- Optional: clear the XS cols if their content doesn't match in height -->
  <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
</div>
```

the tutorial says in this ways this sample will support mobile ,tablet and desktops.
I was confused with this. How bootstrap css works in the sample?
I look the css code and found

```
.col-xs-12 {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-sm-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

.col-md-8 {
  width: 66.66666667%;
}
```

for the `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">` the only worked css will be the `.col-md-8`. So my questions are

1.Is there any special meaning for doing so (I mean apply `col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8` to div )? Actually the only working css class is `col-md-8`.

2.If I want to design a site which can be looked nice in mobile and desktop. How can I implement it with BootStrap css? Please give me some suggestions. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap uses [CSS Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to target specific resolutions.

If you go further down [Bootstrap's CSS file](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css) you'll find things like this:

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
   .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6,
   .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-sm-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  ...
}
```

This specific media query targets browsers with a minimum width of 768px, for instance.

Comment: this is the right answer for the question, but I suggest adding something about the term 'responsive design' to point him to the right direction (and answer subquestion 2)

Comment: @PeterSorowka "responsive design" isn't an official term, and media queries (plus the specification I've linked to) answer both questions.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this question. Please follow my answer to get more knowledge about it.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8"></div>
```

1. When you are in a big screen such as desktop the class "col-md-8" will execute and have most priority over others. So the current div will inherit all css properties of "col-md-8".
2. When you are in small devices like tablet/ipad the class "col-sm-6" will execute and inherit all css properties of "col-sm-6"
3. When you are in extra small devices like phone the class "col-xs-12" will execute and get all the properties of "col-xs-12"

The bottom line is the browser will execute the correct class depending on screen resolutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3+ framework supports nearly all the mobile devices out there except some of the windows devices, because it runs on IE(you know what I mean), but there are fixes for that. it has 4 main types of devices like lg(large),md(medium),sm(small) and xs(xtra small) where rules of each type is automatically converted to other devices, hence making the layout responsive..

Comment: Windows Phone is supported, although you need to apply a hack mentioned in the docs, because (of course) mobile IE is buggy: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie10-width